# Django-filters how to pass current user from view inside FilterSet?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I have a filter where I need to access the request.user. However, Django-filter does not pass it. I was able to figure out possible FilterSet configuration.
But how to pass current user from view inside FilterSet?

*filters.py*

```
class TransationsListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(TransationsListFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    transaction_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs {'placeholder': 'DD/MM/YYYY'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Transations
        fields = ['transaction_date']

    @property
        def qs(self):
        return super(TransationsListFilter, self).filter(user=user)
```

*views.py*

```
class TransactionsList(PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = Transations
    table_class = TransactionsTable
    filter_class = TransationsListFilter
    formhelper_class = TransationsFormHelper
```

*models.py*

```
class Transations(models.Model):
    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default = 0
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with **django-crum** plugin.
 Here is my final code(other files are the same):
*filters.py*

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import DateFromToRangeFilter
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget
from .models import Transations,Account
from crum import get_current_user

class TransationsListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    transaction_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'DD/MM/YYYY'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Transations
        fields = ['transaction_date']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super(TransationsListFilter, self).qs
        return parent.filter(user=get_current_user())
```